# "module not found" even though I didn't ask for this module

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx

Some months ago I made a javafx project for school and it required some external librairies I found on google.

Now I am here trying to do a personal project, so I created a new JavaFX project on intelij Idea, but it keeps shwoing me "module not found" with some of the modules I was using in the previous project... but I have no idea why
There is no "require" anywhere in my code.

[4 module errors, but no require anywhere in any files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPRgq.png)

I tried to reset all setting in Idea and it didnt work, I even created a new project in javafx and it still did the exact same thing

I dont need these modules, how can I remove the errors ?

Comment: Show your `module-info.java` contents.

Comment: This looks like a simple project created by the Idea new JavaFX project wizard.  Re-run the wizard to create a new project with a different name, ensuring you don’t check the checkboxes for any third party JavaFX libraries because you aren’t actually making use of any of those libraries. Use the most recent version of Idea and [follow the instructions exactly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), it will work if you do so.

Comment: Off topic: Don’t use underscores in identifiers if you can avoid it.  [Future versions of Java will use underscores in the language syntax](https://openjdk.org/jeps/443), making underscores in identifiers confusing.

Comment: @CrazyCoder [https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/378243388253929473/1146552484517646406/image.png](here)

Comment: @jewelsea thank you !!  it works without adding anything, but its weird that when I try to add a module, some others pops up even tho I didnt ask for them isnt it??

2nd comment - ok ty :)

Comment: @CrazyCoder *"but its weird that when I try to add a module, some others pops up even tho I didnt ask for them isnt it??"* -> Yes, this due to errors in the new JavaFX project template being applied in Idea when using a TilesFX dependency added by the wizard (I added an answer to explain this).

Answer (score 1):

#### Work-around

This looks like a simple project created by the Idea new JavaFX project wizard.

Re-run the wizard to create a new project with a different name, *ensuring you don’t check the checkboxes for any third-party JavaFX libraries* (because you aren’t actually making use of any of those libraries).

Use the most recent version of Idea and [follow the instructions exactly](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html), it will work if you do so.

#### Why it fails

There are errors in the generated JavaFX project that occur when using the new JavaFX project wizard and including the TilesFX dependency (tested using idea version: Build #IU-232.8660.185, built on July 25, 2023).

1. The version of TilesFX chosen by the Idea project template appears to have malformed module information.
2. TilesFX requires the javafx-swing dependency, which is not included in the Idea project template.

A bug report could be filed with Idea to request a fix.

#### Solution: if you actually *do* need to use TilesFX

The template uses TilesFX version `17.1.17`. This version appears to have some kind of issue with its module definition and generates module errors on build as shown in the question.

Excerpt from a `mvn clean compile` target execution on the generated project:

```
[INFO] --- compiler:3.11.0:compile (default-compile) @ allfx ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module! :source
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files with javac [debug target 20 module-path] to target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] module not found: eu.hansolo.fx.countries
[ERROR] module not found: eu.hansolo.fx.heatmap
[ERROR] module not found: eu.hansolo.toolboxfx
[ERROR] module not found: eu.hansolo.toolbox
[INFO] 4 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This can be fixed, by using the most recent version of TilesFX (`17.1.31` at the time this answer was created).

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>eu.hansolo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tilesfx</artifactId>
    <version>17.1.31</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>*</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

But then you will get another error (also due to a bad template generated by Idea).  This occurs when you try to run the application (by pressing the green run arrow in the IDE when the application class is focused within the IDE).

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module javafx.swing not found, required by eu.hansolo.fx.countries
```

This occurs because Idea is excluding a required dependency in the generated project.  To fix this, add this section to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
    <version>20</version>
</dependency>
```

Adjust the version used to match exactly the version used for the other javafx components in the pom.xml.

Ensure that you [reimport the maven project into Idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/delegate-build-and-run-actions-to-maven.html#maven_reimport).

After making these modifications your application should work fine and be able to make use of TilesFX.